# GCP load-balancer url rewrite not persistent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, gke-networking, gcp-load-balancer

I'm facing a weird issue on GCP, I don't know if it's me using it wrongly or a bug on GCP side.

I recently published a website and I have few redirection to do. But, once I go through the load balancer -> edit -> Host and path rules -> Advanced and set some redirect (path or host and / or with the backend service) everything is showing up and works well... For 10mn.

Then it doesn't work anymore.

Worst part is this, after the first time I've done my configurations:
[image]

I can see my rules being there (and correctly applied). If I click on the edit again in the span of the 5mn following the edit - all is well!

But 10mn later, this is what I see when I click on edit:
[image]

And surprise, if I try my path (mywebsite.io/welcome) it's not working anymore.

Has anyone encountered this issue? I've tried to do the redirect through their console with a yaml file but whatever I do seems incorrect (documentation incorrect?)

If you had any tutorial I would be thankful.

Comment: Did you review the logs of the LB when the rules disappeared? Can you share the logs of your HTTP load Balancer?

Answer (score 1):

Url rewrite is not supported yet for GCE ingress configuration. Because the changes where done manually, the GKE ingress will override and rollback your url rewrites.

Comment: ah.. does it mean I should use a custom nginx in my pod then?

Comment: If you need url rewriting then currently the only option is to use nginx ingress controller indeed. Of course a separate nginx deployment is also possible.